# T-SQL - using STUFF to concatenate grouped columns and removing duplicates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stuff

I have a table that looks like this:

```
EmailAddress: nvarchar(255)
MarketingEmailOptIn: nvarchar(50)
NewsletterOptIn: nvarchar(50)
ThoughtLeaderOptIn: nvarchar(50)
```

[image]

My SQL statement shown below takes the data above and concatenates the "Subscription Type" using a comma as the delimiter:

```
SELECT  
    EmailAddress,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + 
              CASE
                 WHEN B.MarketingEmailOptIn = 'TRUE' THEN 'MarketingEmail' 
                 WHEN B.ThoughtLeaderOptIn = 'TRUE' THEN 'ThoughtLeader'
                 WHEN B.NewsletterOptIn = 'TRUE' THEN 'Newsletter'
              END
          FROM UK_AGT_AgentForms_TEST_DE B 
          WHERE ISNULL(B.EmailAddress, '') = ISNULL(A.EmailAddress, '')
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS Subscriptions
FROM
    UK_AGT_AgentForms_TEST_DE A
GROUP BY 
    EmailAddress
```

Running this SQL produces the following output:

[image]

However notice that `MarketingEmail` is listed twice because the source table ALSO has it listed twice (1st and 2nd rows). I need to omit any duplicate detected, so that my resulting table would look like:

[image]

I'm pretty new to the `STUFF` keyword. I'm just kind of lost on how to detect duplicates at run time - any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Why are the last 3 columns and `nvarchar(50)` when a `varchar(5)` would be sufficient?

Comment: @Larnu no idea.  I'm not at liberty to change up the data structure unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe replace FROM UK_AGT_AgentForms_TEST_DE B with FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM UK_AGT_AgentForms_TEST_DE) B?

Comment: I think `string_agg()` may be a better fit, if it's available to you.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn which is why I was asking for a SQL Version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pewh.  I had to play around with this one.  Maybe not the perfect solution, but I think I was able to achieve what you are trying.  It doesn't use the stuff function though.  It just concats each string and then removes the last comma.

```sql
SELECT EmailAddress, CASE WHEN LEN(Subscriptions) > 0 THEN LEFT(Subscriptions, LEN(Subscriptions) - 1) ELSE '' END AS Subscriptions
FROM (
    SELECT EmailAddress, CONCAT(
            CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN MarketingEmailOptIn = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'MarketingEmail, ' ELSE '' END,
            CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN NewsletterOptIn = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'Newsletter, ' ELSE '' END,
            CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN ThoughtLeaderOptIn = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 THEN 'ThoughLeader, ' ELSE '' END
        ) AS Subscriptions
    FROM UK_AGT_AgentForms_TEST_DE 
    GROUP BY EmailAddress
) AS a
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @Data table (
    EmailAddress nvarchar(255),
    MarketingEmailOptIn nvarchar(50),
    NewsletterOptIn nvarchar(50),
    ThoughtLeaderOptIn nvarchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @Data VALUES
    ( 'mike@mikemarks.com', 'TRUE', NULL, NULL ),
    ( 'mike@mikemarks.com', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', NULL ),
    ( 'mike@mikemarks.com', 'TRUE', NULL, 'TRUE' );

SELECT
    EmailAddress
    , STUFF ( ( CASE WHEN EOptIn = 'TRUE' THEN ',MarketingEmail' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN NOptIn = 'TRUE' THEN ',Newsletter' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN TOptIn = 'TRUE' THEN ',ThoughtLeader' ELSE '' END 
    ), 1, 1, '' ) AS Subscriptions
FROM (

    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
        EmailAddress
        , MAX ( MarketingEmailOptIn ) AS EOptIn
        , MAX ( NewsletterOptIn ) AS NOptIn
        , MAX ( ThoughtLeaderOptIn ) AS TOptIn
    FROM @Data A --UK_AGT_AgentForms_TEST_DE
    GROUP BY EmailAddress
    ORDER BY EmailAddress

) AS x
ORDER BY 
    EmailAddress;
```

Returns

```
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|    EmailAddress    |              Subscriptions              |
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| mike@mikemarks.com | MarketingEmail,Newsletter,ThoughtLeader |
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Sql Server 2017 or later, you can use `String_agg()` to simplify this:

```
SELECT   
    EmailAddress,
        STRING_AGG(CASE
                 WHEN MarketingEmailOptIn = 'TRUE' THEN 'MarketingEmail' 
                 WHEN ThoughtLeaderOptIn = 'TRUE' THEN 'ThoughtLeader'
                 WHEN NewsletterOptIn = 'TRUE' THEN 'Newsletter'
              END, ', ') AS Subscriptions
FROM
    UK_AGT_AgentForms_TEST_DE
GROUP BY 
    EmailAddress
```

If you still see duplicates, you can use conditional aggregation in a nested query to roll it up first:

```
SELECT  
    EmailAddress,
          CASE WHEN MarketingEmailOptIn > 0 THEN 'MarketingEmail,' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN ThoughtLeaderOptIn > 0 THEN 'ThoughtLeader,' ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN NewsletterOptIn = > 0 THEN 'Newsletter' ELSE '' END
         AS Subscriptions
FROM (
    SELECT EmailAddress
        , SUM(CASE WHEN MarketingEmailOptIn = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MarketingEmailOptIn
        , SUM(CASE WHEN ThoughtLeaderOptIn = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ThoughtLeaderOptIn
        , SUM(CASE WHEN NewsletterOptIn = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NewsletterOptIn
    FROM UK_AGT_AgentForms_TEST_DE
    GROUP BY EmailAddress
) T
```